# Jquery function working in Chrome Console but not in the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Using Wp-optin plugin and I want to display the form first before the wheel. I've written some jQuery script to hide the wheel and only show the form first, after the form has been filled, it will make the button active and when clicked it will show the wheel. the script works on console window but when I use it on the code it is not taking in effect.

below is the code and the link:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("div.wof-wheel .wof-left").hide();
$('button.wof-btn-submit').prop("disabled", true);
$('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) { 
 
        validateInputs();
    });
    $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
    $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
    $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').on('keyup change drop paste', function(event) {
        validateInputs();
    });
    function validateInputs(){
        var disableButton = false;
      
        var val1 = $('[data-wof-field~="primary_email"]').val();
        var val2 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_2"]').val();
        var val3 = $('[data-wof-field~="number_1"]').val();
        var val4 = $('[data-wof-field~="text_1"]').val();

        if(val1.length == 0 || val2.length == 0 || val3.length == 0 || val4.length == 0){
            disableButton = true;
            $('button.wof-btn-submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        }
      
      if(!disableButton){
        $('button.wof-btn-submit').prop("disabled", false);
      }
    }
     $("button").click(function() {
    $("div.wof-wheel .wof-left").show();
    $("div.wof-wheel .wof-right").hide();
    $("div.wof-wheel .wof-left").delay(9000).hide(400);
    $("div.wof-wheel .wof-right").delay(9000).show(400);
    
  });
});
```

[link](https://bathandbodyworks-rewards.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The [`wheel.js`](https://bathandbodyworks-rewards.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/js/wheel.js) file in the link you provided doesn't contains the code you have provided in the Question.
Can you please confirm if your changes were really uploaded to the server and there's no server side caching ?